# Podio API get user email from ShareFile SSO

Tags: podio, sharefile

I'm having issues getting a user's email address if the user uses ShareFile SSO.

Calling `/user/status` only shows me the email address that the user originally used to sign up in the `user` object.

The user has since changed their email address in ShareFile, but Podio is not returning any mention of this new address.

Is there any other way to get this data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that information would be available via the Podio API. The /user/status API call fetches the Podio account information which isn't necessarily the same email as the ShareFile account and token you are tied to.

I think you'd want to run the get user API call on the SF account. See documentation here: https://api.sharefile.com/rest/docs/resource.aspx?name=Users